# Will the ImageView redo all the process again when the input image is same?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

I am wondering when the same image resource is set to the imageView again, will the imageView redo all the processes? (The size of imageView and size of image does not change.)

Like the following scenario

```
imageview.setImageBitmap(b);
imageview.setImageBitmap(b);
```

Comment: I suggest you look at the source of ImageView: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/ImageView.java;l=100?q=ImageView&sq=

Comment: After study the source code I found that `setImageResource` will reset the imageView every time even with same resource. However the `setDrawable` and `setImageBitmap` will detect whether the resource is the same. I am not sure if I understand correctly.